# android studio gradle dependencies fails with no error

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, parse-platform, gradle

I'm using the gradle build script, in android studio to fetch the Parse android SDK, as follow:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
}
```

The build process succeeds with no errors, yet , when I the to `import com.parse.Parse;` I get `cannot resolve symbol parse`.

To my understanding, that build script was supposed to download the Parse SDK from a maven repository, and build it, or otherwise to fail.

Where do I have wrong?

Comment: add parse module in project

Comment: @Prachi why isn't it downloading it automatically as it does with other lilbs?

Comment: you have added parse lib- third pary lib rt ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [Parse's Android Studio guide](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android) again, you'll see this:
[image]

**Step 1** instructs you to download the SDK.

**Step 2** asks you to first put Parse-*.java to the project's libs folder, and *then* add the script you've shown in your question into build.gradle. Notice that the library pulled from maven is just an auxiliary library, not the Parse library itself. This is why Android Studio cannot find the Parse class.

Comment: why would they do that? it makes the part (2) completely redundant.

Comment: @nobatlinux Well not exactly. The reasons appears to be that their library is not on Maven Central, so it has to be dropped into _/libs_  directory as it has been in Eclipse. So the code to add to build.gradle is to: **a.** make sure _Parse-*.jar_ in _/libs_ are compiled, and **b.** download and compile the most up-to-date version of _bolt_. My guess is that they'll eventually move their library to Maven as well, thus skipping Step 1 and the first half of Step 2.

Comment: I think not Parse are on Maven.  Can someone please provide detail about how to implement it?  :)